# Multiplication Rule Probability

Tags: combinatorics

Question is : Registrants at a large convention are offered $6$
sightseeing tours on each of $3$ days. In how many
ways can a person arrange to go on a sightseeing tour
planned by this convention?

I thought answer is $6\cdot 6\cdot 6 = 216$ because a person can choose 6 tours each day. But my book says : With $n_1 = 6$ sightseeing tours each available on $n_2 = 3$ different days, the multiplication
rule gives $n_1\cdot n_2 = (6)(3) = 18$ ways for a person to arrange a tour.

How can it be $18$ ways?

Comment: Note that the question is 'how many ways can a person arrange to go on **a** sightseeing tour'. One good check is to try and list more than 18 ways to go on **a** tour. Can you?

Comment: The inclusion of the phrase 'on each of 3 days' does make the question somewhat confusing. It sounds like a person can take a tour on each day.

Answer (score 2):

(sorry, this is more of a comment, but my rep is too low to post it like that)

I would say that the question *is* somewhat ambiguous, it doesn't explicitly state a person is allowed to go on **only one** trip, although by the answer that obviously is what they meant.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
- & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline
1 & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
2 & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
3 & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
\end{array}$$
You are only allowed to go on $1$ trip, you may pick the trip and the day you go on it, giving $18$ options.